# How to move a line of sprites in a sine wave?

Tags: xna, 2d, mathematics

So, I'm spawning a horizontal line of enemies that I would like to have move in a nice wave.  Currently I tried:

```
 Enemy.position.X += Enemy.velocity.X;
 Enemy.position.Y += -(float)Math.Cos(Enemy.position.X / 200) * 5;
```

This...kind of works.  But the wave is not a true wave.  The top and bottom of one pass are not the same (e.g. 5 for the top, and -5 for the bottom (I don't mean literal points, I just meant that it's not symmetrical)).

Is there a better way to do this?  I would like the whole line to move in a wave, so it looks fluid.  By that, I mean that it should look like each enemy is "following" the one in front of it.  The code I posted does have this fluidity to it, but like I said, it's not a perfect wave.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your window size 200?

Comment: How is it not a perfect wave? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosine%28X+%2F+200%29+*+5) suggests your formula is just fine. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: No, no.  My window size is 1280x720.  I should have specified.  That's just my arbitrary number to constrain the wave so it's not giant.

Comment: [This is the wave](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosine%28X+%2F+200%29++5+from+0+to+1280) you should expect for your window size

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the functions you guys provided, it is a little strange that it doesn't work. Give me a moment to try something.  EDIT:  It works fine if I just spawn 1 enemy.  It's only the trailing enemies that have issues.  It looks like the trailing enemies are a bit "lower" to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's as simple as:

```
Enemy.position.X += Enemy.velocity.X;
Enemy.position.Y = -(float)Math.Cos(Enemy.position.X / 200) * 5;
```

Notice the `Enemy.position.Y` is just using `=` not `+=`

**EDIT**

Try with this instead:

```
Enemy.position.Y = -(float)Math.Cos(Enemy.position.X / 100);
```

**EDIT again**

With offset to put 0 at the middle of your window:

```
Enemy.position.Y = -(float)Math.Cos(Enemy.position.X / 100) + ScreenHeight/2;
```

OR

```
Enemy.position.Y = StartPosition.Y + (-(float)Math.Cos(position.X / 100) * 100);
```

As you found that to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  That eliminates the wave entirely, and the enemies just move across the top of the screen (0 on the Y)

Comment: That's pretty strange. Clearly the Y value couldn't equal zero, what are the Y values being set to? [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-cosine%28X%2F100%29+from+0+to+1280) is what should be happening with the new setting.

Comment: Alright, now we're getting somewhere.  With the /100 I can now see that, while still being 'centered' around 0, it is still doing a very slight wave.  So now maybe I need to offset it?

Comment: Success! Here's the new line: position.Y = OriginalPosition.Y + (-(float)Math.Cos(position.X / 100) * 100); This makes a fantastic wave. Many thanks, Byte. You nudged me in the right direction.  If you change your answer to relect the line I just stated, I'll mark you as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as: `Enemy.position.Y = -(float)Math.Sin(Enemy.position.X)`, no?

This assumes you have a wave of enemies that move horizontally. The path of motion would be the exact same as the plot of y = sin x, or rather Enemy.position.Y = sin(Enemy.position.X).